# How many times can you activate an ignition effect per turn in yu-gi-oh?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I tried reading the rule book and it didn't say if there was a limit how many times you could do it. I assume there must be. Given a monster with an ignition effect, how many times can I activate it per turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given a monster with an ignition effect, how many times can I activate it per turn?

Short answer is **each card or monster will specify the number of times that you can activate their effects.**

Usually this is written in the form of *"Once per turn..."*, or *"During your Main phase..."*. Some may say "twice", some even say *"Once per Duel"*, etc..

In more general terms this is written in the form of:

> "[Times it can be activated]+[Conditions needed to activate], [cost for activating]; [the effect]"

Comment: Catapult turtle doesn't say anything like that though...

Comment: @temporary_user_name Yes it does. The text reads "Once per turn". Perhaps you are looking at an old printing of the card? See https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Catapult_Turtle

Comment: @temporary_user_name to be more precise, Catapult Turtle's effect was changed. Previously it didn't had restrictions but now it does have an Errata that changed it to Once per turn (as to avoid OTK or FTK). See https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Errata:Catapult_Turtle. More recent printings do say "Once per turn".

Comment: @temporary_user_name furthermore, if a card (on it's most recent printing) does not say anything about Once per turn whatsoever it means it can be activated any times you wanted as long as you can pay the cost.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I had the second version. Is the fandom wiki the definitive source for errata?

Comment: @temporary_user_name the definitive source is Konami. However, the Wiki is a very thorough and up to date site... It's a solid resource if I may say. If any, you can find the most recent printing of any card there (or googling) and then google what Konami has said about them. For example this is the most recent printing of the Turtle.DL18-EN001

Comment: I see this list of errata... Are there really only nine updated cards? https://img.yugioh-card.com/uk/gameplay/detail.php?id=415

Comment: @temporary_user_name it seems like so... at least in a way that changed the original effect of the card, like when they Killed Ring Of destruction. Other changes like wording or more clear phrasing are not erratas AFAIK